# JavaScript: Regex for numbers that include decimal and fractional parts with optional leading minus sign?

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I have tried to run the following regex:

```
(-?\d+\.?(\d*)?)
```

which works very well when I try it on https://regex101.com/r/lD2qB4/5

But when I apply it to my JavaScript code, it doesn't accept leading minus sign!

What could be the reason for something like that?

***Inputs that 'should' match:***

- 123.456
- 123456.
- -123.456

***Inputs that 'should not' match:***

- 123.456.
- 123456..
- --123.456

**EDIT:**

Code snippet:

```
private validateNumber() {
        let newValue: string = $(this.getNativeElement()).val();
        if (/(-?\d+\.?(\d*)?)/.test(newValue)) {
            let min = (this.options.min) ? this.options.min : this.numberTypesRenges.get(this.options.numberType).min;
            let max = (this.options.max) ? this.options.max : this.numberTypesRenges.get(this.options.numberType).max;
            if (+newValue >= min && +newValue <= max) {
                this.prevValue = newValue;
            } else {
                this.ngModel.reset(this.prevValue);
            }
        } else {
            this.ngModel.reset(this.prevValue);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem is most probably with your code. Please post it.

Comment: I'll suggest `/^[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?$/.test(string)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Done

Comment: @Tushar Unfortunately, this doesn't accept any leading characters and not even the decimal point

Comment: @BilalAhmed You need to trim the value. Are there any other _leading characters_?  Check [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/VzUZkV/1)

Comment: @Tushar I think it's an issue with my code since my regex and yours both work in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one issue

```
/^(-?\d+(\.\d+)?$/
^^^           ^^
```

The start and end. Otherwise it will do partial match.

Also, you can group the optional `.\d` together

AS   `(\.\d+)` instead of `.?\d*?

Note that `*` means `0 or more` so, it will match `1.`.

Instead use `+` for `1 or more`

Comment: Yes I know that * means 0 or more and that's how I expect my regex to behave. Unfortunately, I tried your regex but It didn't work as expected. 
I also tried using full match using /^(....)?$/ but also didn't work